# Reference request: Proof that every product of vector space is isomorphic to the tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

On Wikipedia, it says

> On every tangent bundle $TM$, considered as a manifold itself, one can
>   define a canonical vector field $V : TM → TTM$ as the diagonal map on
>   the tangent space at each point. This is possible because the tangent
>   space of a vector space W is naturally a product, $TW \cong W \times
> W$, since the vector space itself is flat

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle

Does anyone know if there is a proof that $TW \cong W \times
W$? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any point $p\in W$, any vector $v\in W$, one can define a path $\gamma:t\mapsto p + t v$: clearly $\gamma(0) =p$ and  $\gamma'(0)=v$. Conversely, given a path $\gamma$, with $\gamma (0) =p$, $$ {\gamma(h) -\gamma (0)\over h }\in W,$$
for all (small, say) non-zero $h$.
Hence, $\gamma'(0)\in W$. Therefore, we have the natural identification  $TW = \{(p,v) \in W\times W \}$.

*Addition*
The following is in response to the comment below asking for motivation and a clarification about 'what is' $T_xW$.

I think most people secretly think of the tangent space $T_xW$ fairly concretely, a la vector calculus, much as above, as the space of derivatives $\gamma'(0)$ of curves $\gamma:\mathbb R \to W$ through the point $x=\gamma(0)$. This works, as is, if one knows that the manifold is sitting inside some kind of ambient Euclidean space, because then we can calculate and define a tangent vector $v$ by

$$ v= \gamma'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} {\gamma(0+h) -\gamma(0)\over h}.$$ 
That is, one can do this because the above difference, quotient, and  limit make sense. For general manifolds $W$, one has to go through some kind formalism for any definition or calculation, but the result has to be consistent with above. I would say that the sages have done this by replacing the frame work provided by an'ambient space' with one that uses nice test  functions $f \colon W \to \mathbb R$: the composition $f\circ \gamma$ is a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, so one  can again understand 
$$ {d\over dt}\Bigg\rvert_{t=0}\, f \circ \gamma = \lim_{h\to 0} {(f\circ\gamma)\,(0+h) -(f\circ\gamma)\,(0)\over h}.$$
At this point one identifies a tangent vector $v$ with the set of $\gamma$ for which the preceding gives the same result for any fixed test function $f$, i.e., one defines $v$ as functional (function on some set of functions - or more correctly, on some set of equivalence classes of functions) by the formula

$$ v(f)= {d\over dt}\Bigg\rvert_{t=0}\, f \circ \gamma,$$
for some equivalence class of $\gamma$. 
This matches up with the vector calculus version, because of the chain rule.

How one does this - or how the sages do this - formally and rigorously depends on the approach to define a manifold - i.e. by charts and atlases, or as a locally ringed space - and what equivalent choice of definition of 'functional' one uses (derivation, or as an element of the dual $m/m^2$, where $m$ is the maximal ideal of functions - or equivalence classes of functions - vanishing at $x$)...  One has to show that given the 'functional' $v$ - i.e., 'the' tangent vector $v$ - that there is a corresponding curve $\gamma$ - but that is 'clear' because of charts, say, and because one can do so in $\mathbb R^n$. For a more complete and (somewhat  official) reference, see the "Formal Definitions" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space.

N.B. I hope that this addition motivates and explains the first part of the answer - i.e., given a point $x\in W$, and $v\in W$ ($W$ is now not the arbitrary manifold, but the vector space), there is a corresponding curve $\gamma$ such that $\gamma(0)= x$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$, and vice versa; this identification corresponds to the construction above. Hence we can identify $T_xW =  W$, and $TW= W\times W$.

Comment: Sorry peter I like your answer but I have no idea what it is doing. Can you show the motivation for this construction and what this construction shows exactly? Thank you! And similarly how can this be done to show that $W \cong T_xW$ where $T_xW$ is the tangent space at x?

Comment: @FemaleTank - see the "Addition" above - I hope it helps!