# Question about the notion of a tangent vector to a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm currently learning differential geometry on my own (as a supplement to my class on General Relativity), and I'm aware that there are a variety of ways to define the tangent vector to a manifold $M$.

Here, I'm mostly interested in the 'velocity curve' approach. Basically, from what I understand, when you have a manifold $M$ and a point $p \in M$, you can have a curve $\gamma: I \subset \mathbb{R} \to M$ such that $\gamma(0) = p$. One then defines the tangent vector to the curve $\gamma$ at $t = 0$ as a **function** $\gamma': C^{\infty}(M) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $$ \gamma' (0) f = \frac{d}{dt} |_{t=0} (f \circ \gamma)$$ where $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is some function.

So a tangent vector is a function, which can act on smooth mappings. But my question is: why doesn't one just define the tangent vector at a point $p \in M$ as the 'velocity vector' of the curve $\gamma$, i.e. just as $\vec{v} = \gamma'(0)$ ? We can differentiate the curve $\gamma$ because this is just a function from an interval of the real numbers to $M$.

Why must the tangent vector act on mappings? Am I missing something here, because I really don't see why one complicates matters so much.

Comment: Maybe the 'addition' to my answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617438/reference-request-proof-that-every-product-of-vector-space-is-isomorphic-to-the/1617453#1617453 helps...

Comment: Please, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2529245/tangent-spaces-and-local-approximations-of-manifolds/2529305#2529305).

Comment: The whole issue is how one can define $\gamma'(0)$ to begin with. For that, one needs the notion of a tangent vector.