# On the definition of a vector field on manifolds.

Tags: vector-spaces, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Here is the definition i found in my book on topology and geometry:

"A vector field $\zeta$ on an n-dimensional manifold $M$ is a function such that $\zeta(p)\in T_pM$ and such that given local coordinates $x_1, ... ,x_n$ near p such that $\zeta(p) = \sum_i a_i(p)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ the $a_i$ are smooth functions."

All of this seems a little complicated and informal, why not say that a vector field on an n-dimensional manifold $M$ is a smooth map $M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ since you often regard $T_pM$ as $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ anyways? Or am i mistaken in that $T_pM$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for all such M?

Cheers.

Comment: Do you know the concept of the **tangent bündle** $TM$ of a differentiable manifold $M$?

Comment: Indeed, you can take isomorphisms between $T_pM$ and $\Bbb R^n$, indexed by $p$. But you can't ensure that this family of isomorphisms varies smoothly with $p$. So you can't do this to define vector fields *globally* along $M$. This is related to whether the tangent bundle $TM$ is trivial or not.

Comment: Yes, I do. Not much more than the definition though.

Comment: A purer definition of a vector field may be _a smooth map $X$ of $M$ into $TM$ such that $\pi\circ X=id $ _ . But in my opinion it is too 'rude' for a first course in differential geometry. In my opinion your definition is good. If $M$ is space which locally seems $\mathbb R^n$, a vector field must be a map such that locally can be studied as a vector field of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Well your definition certainly sidesteps my issue with the original definition being too "handwavy" and is certainly neater than my one. Thank you! Regarding your second point I was wondering if this could be extended to a global map and be studied accordingly. For example the 0 vector field would just be the constant map from M to {0} and the contant vector field on $S^{1}$ would just be a map $S^{1} \rightarrow 1$ .

Comment: I think you mean if there is an ipen neighbourhood such that the vector field can be express as an 'euclidean' vector field (i.e. your expression of $zeta(p)$ is valid for any $p\in M$ without changing the chart). In this case the answer is not unless the manifold is parallelizable, which means precisely that. For example, the Möbius strip is not parallelizable: every section vanishes at least at one point.

Comment: Oh, I realize my mistake now. I won't bother you anymore! Thanks.

Comment: @NoelLundström Maybe my addendum to my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617438/reference-request-proof-that-every-product-of-vector-space-is-isomorphic-to-the/1617453#1617453 might be of some interest to you...  It motivates/explains the def of tangent vectors (but not vector fields - still...).

Comment: @NoelLundström Dont' worry :)

Comment: It's been two years since I asked this question and understand the tangent bundle quite well now :P @Masacroso

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example demonstrating the difference. Let $M=S^2$. Each tangent space $T_pM$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$, and the constant function $f:p\mapsto(1,0)$ is a smooth, nowhere-vanishing map $M\to\Bbb R^2$. But by the [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem), every vector field on the sphere vanishes somewhere.

The problem is that the global topological structure of $S^2$ prevents us from identifying every point's tangent space with $\Bbb R^2$ in a continuous way. In other words, the [tangent bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle) $TM$ is not homeomorphic to the product space $M\times\Bbb R^2$.